# Is this possible to increase speed of processors in NiFi?

Tags: apache-nifi

I need some clarifications in NiFi Processors.

Since each processor have concurrent tasks if i have set the concurrent tasks for processors then it boosts processing speed of processors.But it affects the System performance such as 100% Disk Usage,100% Memory Usage..etc

Is there is any other way to speed up processors without use concurrent tasks?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Quoting @joe-witt reply to you n the mailing list:

> For processors that support it consider using a 'run duration of 25
>   milliseconds'.  This allows the framework to batch many operations
>   into fewer transactions which can dramatically increase throughput.
>
> 100% memory usage is a problem.  Increase heap size or consider
>   redesign/simplifying your flow.
>
> 100% disk usage should be addressed.  Ensure each repository is on a
>   physically separate partition.  If this is not possible then keep in
>   mind they will create congestion for eachother or consider switching
>   to a volatile provenance repository.
>
> Review the flow for processors which load content fully into memory.
>   This can harm performance greatly.

[Source: https://lists.apache.org/thread.html/8468ee0c03e81644b7fcd8a464a706670cc06bf0c564a300121307a9@%3Cusers.nifi.apache.org%3E](https://lists.apache.org/thread.html/8468ee0c03e81644b7fcd8a464a706670cc06bf0c564a300121307a9@%3Cusers.nifi.apache.org%3E)